# Prove rigorously that the functions $f(z)$ and $\overline{f(\overline{z})}$ are simultaneously analytic.

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove rigorously that the functions $f(z)$ and $\overline{f(\overline{z})}$ are simultaneously analytic.

From where do i start and what does simultaneouslt means here?

Any help is appreciated ?

Comment: $f$ is analytic on $U\subseteq_{\text{open}}\Bbb C\iff z\mapsto \overline{f(\overline z)},z\in \overline U:=\{\overline z\in \Bbb C| z\in U\}$ is analytic.

Comment: I just started complex analysis so it would be better if you explain in simple terms

Comment: "Simultaneously" means what that duplicate question says.  But using the word "simultaneously" like this can be confusing, and should be avoided.